Sap Business Application Studio : layout editor error in XML views
I have a Fiori project in Sap BAS. It contains 2 views.
Project1
 -> webapp
   -> view
      -> View1.view.xml
      -> View2.view.xml

Index.html contains:
data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{ "project1": "./" }'

View1 contains an xml view for View2:
<mvc:XMLView viewName="project1.view.View2/>

When I run the app, it displays correctly the view2 in the view1.
But when I start the Layout editor for View1, it drops the following error:

For scenarios involving fragments and nested views, your project must contain an index.html like or a localIndex.html file containing the data-sap-resourceroots attribute. Currently, your project does not contain such files.
resource project1/view/View2.view.xml could not be loaded from /di/home/user/projects/project1/webapp/./view/View2.view.xml. Check for 'file not found' or parse errors. Reason:

Anybody has a clue what did I wrong?
Thanks for the help
I tried to modify the link to view2 several mode, but always error comes.

In your error it says data-sap-resourceroots. In your index.html it says data-sap-ui-resourceroots. Could this be the problem?

Thanks for the recommendation. Unfortunately not helped :(
